# LibreOffice SpreadSheet Conditionally copy value from one cell into a second cell?

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice

I'd like to have the calculated value of a cell be carried over to another cell if the result is less than a given value.

For instance, cell A2 is defined as =A1*.75
If the result is less than x, I'd like the result to be inserted into B2.

This would be similar to B2=IF( A2 < x; INDIRECT("A2") ) but rather A2 assigning the value to B2 based on the result.

Comment: Why not just repeat the formula? `=IF((A1*0.75)>x;A1*0.75;0)`?

Comment: huh.  well, I didn't think of that.  It would work, if there isn't a mechanism to do what I originally was asking.